# Equivalent of php's chr in golang

Tags: go, ascii, chr

i am try to change a fuction from php to golang . the function job is use chr,ord,base4_encode to encode some string。php generate a serial int number, like 122|234|135|138|179|19|190|183|80|156|4|159|195|213|86|241|140|7|112|23|61|182|37|91|185|26|203|185|206|206|183,
some number biger than 127,the ascii bigest number is 127.
now, the probrem is:
php's chr(206) is not equivalent golang's string(rune(206))

please help me,thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results in PHP and Go are different because, as the documentation for each states, [PHP's chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) returns the ASCII character for its argument, whereas [Go's rune](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) [uses UTF-8](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals). Below 127, ASCII and UTF-8 are the same, but above that, they differ.